# General version of M-test of the uniform convergence of real-valued function to arbitrary metric space also holds?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, uniform-convergence

In the mafred stoll, Real analysis, p.326 ( 8.2.6 Theorem ) he state that

> 8.2.5 Theorem. Suppose the sequence $\{f_n\}$ of real-valued functions on the set $E$ converges pointwise to $f$ on $E$. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, set

$$ M_n:= \sup_{x\in E}|f_n(X) -f(x)|$$

Then $\{f_n\}$ converges unifomly to $f$ on $E$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to \infty} M_n =0$.

**Q.** Perhaps, the theorem also holds when we replace $E$ by arbitrary (sub) metric space ? Definition of uniform convergence on metric space is as https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Uniform_Convergence/Metric_Space.  I can't find any related information.

Comment: yes,its fine...

Comment: You need your function space to be complete (which makes t is)- the M test show that the partial sums of the series form a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @krm2233 : You mean, "requirement of the $E$ above is complete metric space"?

Comment: No, the space of functions in which the $f_n$s lie must be complete, so that the Cauchy sequence of partial sums has a limit.

Comment: For what norm/metric do you mean that the space of function is complete? Let's consider for example $E:= \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ ( the sphere). Then such space of functions is complete?

Comment: @krm2233 this is not the Weierstrass $M$-test for series of functions (with values in a normed spaces (for which indeed, completeness is equivalent to convergence of all absolutely convergent series)). Here, the vanishing of $M_n$ is literally the definition of uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$, when these functions take values in a metric space (complete or not), once we replace $M_n$ with $\sup\limits_{x\in E}d(f_n(x),f(x))$. The domain can be any set.

Comment: @peek-a-boo : Thanks for peek-a-boo !

Comment: @peek-a-boo thanks for catching that! It's a bizarre "result" to state as a theorem though.

Comment: Yea… at best it is a mini exercise in working with supremums and relating it to the ‘usual’ phrasing of the definition with full-on quantifiers.

Comment: @peek-a-boo You're right, I guess it could be an exercise on "sups".  Then again, I find it bizarre that textbooks don't usually point out that the proof of the M-test gives you a criterion for uniform convergence for any space of functions taking values in a complete metric space (even though most of what they are doing at the time is using 1-variable ideas and the notion of a metric space to prove results of much greater generality) e.g. most books prove the contraction mapping theorem by proving the special case of $M_n=c.K^n$ ($c>0, K\in (0,1)$).